How to lazy import React component js build by vite in **tauri2**?
I want to dynamic import some client pages for my host page after click one button in tauri2. The client pages are external library, and they are written using ReactJS. Something like this:
import {Form} from 'antd';
import {useEffect} from "react";

export default function Config() {
  const [configForm] = Form.useForm();
  useEffect(() => {
    configForm.setFieldsValue(someInitalValues)
  }

  return (
    <Form form={configForm}>
      something item...
    </Form>
  )
}

I use vite to build my client jsx to js. The vite.config.js follows as:
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/Config.jsx'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'my-lib',
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

My host page is written using ReactJS too. My lazy import code follows as:
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import {convertFileSrc} from "@tauri-apps/api/core";

// My client js files local path. The path come from my backend.
const comp_path = "X:/.../my-lib.js";
// Convert local path to url by tauri convertFileSrc.
const comp_url_path = convertFileSrc(comp_path);
// Lazy import my client js.
const Config = lazy(() => import(comp_url_path));

return (
  <>
    ...
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading</div>}>
      <Config />
    </Suspense >
    ...
  </>
)

I config my tauri.conf.json in order to allow my js to read local js file, follows as:
{
  ...
  "app": {
    ...,
    "security": {
      "assetProtocol": {
        "enable": true,
        "scope": ["**"]
      },
      "csp": "script-src 'self' asset: http://asset.localhost"
    }
  },
  ...
}

After doing the above things, I run my app by pnpm tauri dev. When I click the button to call my client page, and console tell me:
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

From the information I think my host page has imported my local js file, but the host page cannot share its react module  to the client js. I think I can include react module in my client js, so I modify my vite.config.js, follows as:
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/Config.jsx'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'my-lib',
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // external: ['react', "react-dom"],
      // output: {
      //   globals: {
      //     react: 'React',
      //     "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
      //   },
      // },
    },
  },
})


After run my tauri app, I don't have TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react", but I have other ERROR and a lot of WARNING:
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

I've been stuck for a week now... Who can help me to solve this problem?

where is the file that you are trying to import, is it within a dir inside your project? I don't think this will work with dynamic import X:. As the error says, the path must be either relative (start with ./) or absolute (start with /, resolved relative to the project root).

My client js files are outside my project. I want to be able to expand the external library freely without rebuilding my project every time. So I chose to read my client js file path dynamically, and pass the file path to lazy import.
